# Using constructor injection when caller expects a specific constructor signature

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm new to DI in .NET C# & autofac and having problems to understand how to use DI when I can't fully control the caller side.

There are two scenarios I have problems to understand.

### Scenario 1: Caller expects a default constructor (without any parameters)

How to handle this scenario when I still want to inject some Service Interfaces when the class is constructed? I was thinking of constructor chaining, but that would mean I have to know the concrete type and it works around the idea of DI. (at least I think).

```
public class ServiceWorker
{
    IService _service;

    public ServiceWorker(IService service) 
    { 
        _service = service
    }
}

public class Caller
{
    // No way to change this. 
    var serviceWorker = new ServiceWorker();
}
```

### Scneario 2: Caller expects a specific constructor signature (e.g.

Same question here. How can I inject additional dependencies when the caller expects an exact match for the constructor signature?

I think my main issue in understanding the concept is, that I don't see how to do DI only partially when not everything is constructed by DI (caller)

```
public class ServiceWorker
{
    IService _service;

    public ServiceWorker(string name, string id, IService service) 
    { 
        _service = service
    }
}

public class Caller
{
    // No way to change this. 
    var serviceWorker = new ServiceWorker(name, id);
}
```

I know, this is pretty basic, but I believe I need to understand this first before moving on. Are there alternatives?

Comment: With DI, as is the case with async/await, "all the way down" is your friend.

Comment: I think so - what would be the next best approach to face this? Property Injection or calling the Container to resolve inline code of the required constructor (It looks not so beautiful to me).

Comment: Why isn't Caller constructed by the DI container, with a constructor taking a ServiceWorker instance?

Comment: In my case, the "Caller" is coming from a 3rd party, so I can't modify the internal behavior which is highly expecting to have a specific signature. I believe there is some reflection involved.

Comment: If you can't modify it, you should be using a factory in the composition root to construct the dependencies or you should be wrapping the 3rd party component.

Comment: You could make `ServiceWorker` a proxy/factory that uses the "expected" signatures but internally creates `ActualServiceWorker` that takes the injected dependencies.

Comment: From the autofac documentation (In my case, the factory would use this anti-pattern, right?)

Note: generally speaking, service location is largely considered an anti-pattern (see article). That is, manually creating scopes everywhere and sprinkling use of the container through your code is not necessarily the best way to go. Using the Autofac integration libraries you usually won’t have to do what we did in the sample app above. Instead, things get resolved from a central, “top level” location in the application and manual resolution is rare. Of course, how you design your app is up to you.

Comment: That may be true, but in your case (if I understand correctly) you do not have the luxury of affecting the "top level" because its "coming from 3rd party". If you can't go "all the way down" you need to pick a starting point (e.g. `ServiceWorker`) and go DI from there and work out how (factory/proxy/whatever) to wire it up for "external" use. Adding DI later can be/is a pain in the proverbial.

Comment: thanks a lot. I was thinking that I completely missed the concept of DI...At least I feel good now ;-) Thank you all.

Comment: The concept of having a class that is forced to have a specific constructure signature, is called **Constrained Construction**. It is an anti-pattern, but sometimes unavoidable when forced upon you from a 3rd party tool. The typical solution is to make that class a **[Humble Object](http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html)** where that object becomes as thin as possible and only directly resolves one service directly from the DI container. Such Humble Object can be seen as part of the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Steven correctly points out in his comment, being restricted to a specific constructor signature is an instance of the **Constrained Construction** anti-pattern. Sometimes, however, that can be outside your control.

An example is the [so-called 'Provider pattern', which isn't a pattern at all](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/04/27/Providerisnotapattern). In such an example, you may have to play by the rules of a third-party framework, so there isn't much you can do about it. Such frameworks should be considered unfriendly to Dependency Injection.

Consider scenario 2 in the OP, since scenario 1 is just a special case of scenario 2. If you *must* supply a class with a certain constructor, you could create a [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) that has the required constructor signature. This enables you to avoid polluting your well-designed classes that use Dependency Injection with the constraints imposed by the third-party framework. It could look like this:

```
public class ServiceWorker
{
    IService _service;

    public ServiceWorker(string name, string id, IService service) 
    { 
        _service = service
    }
}

public class ServiceWorkerFacade
{
    ServiceWorker imp;

    public ServiceWorkerFacade(string name, string id) 
    { 
        imp =
            new ServiceWorker(
                name,
                id,
                new FooService(
                    new BarService(),
                    new BazService());
    }
}

public class Caller
{
    // No way to change this. 
    var serviceWorker = new ServiceWorkerFacade(name, id);
}
```

`FooService` implements `IService`. Just to make things interesting, I've assumed that `FooService` has dependencies of its own, and that those dependencies are satisfied by `BarService` and `BazService`.

As Steven suggests, then, you can (from necessity) consider the Facade's constructor the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot).

If you have any opportunity to influence the design of the framework in question, you could point the developers to [my guidance on designing DI-friendly frameworks](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework).